# How can I click an element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, highcharts

I am trying to click an element on a pie chart when I hover over another element, for which I am using HighChart. However under the mouseover function when I try to click the element I am getting an error which says that "click is not a function".Basically, I want to hover over Apple slice when someone hovers over H1 tag Here is what I have tried:

```js
debugger;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 45
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Contents of Highsoft\'s weekly fruit delivery'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      innerSize: 100,
      depth: 45
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Delivered amount',
    data: [
      ['Bananas', 8],
      ['Kiwi', 3],
      ['Mixed nuts', 1],
      ['Oranges', 6],
      ['Apples', 8],
      ['Pears', 4],
      ['Clementines', 4],
      ['Reddish (bag)', 1],
      ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
    ]
  }]
});

var ch = document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-color-4");
var bx = document.getElementById("Apples");
var cv = bx;

if (ch && bx) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    ch[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
  }
  bx.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
}

function mouseOver() {
  $("#Apples").css("color", "red");
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-color-4");
  if (c) {
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      c[i].click();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<h1 id="Apples">Apples</h1>
```

Here is the link for [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/suLjtqb5/6/)

Comment: `c[i]` is not a jQuery object on which you could invoke the jQuery function `.click()`, doing `$(c[i]).click()` should work

Comment: Do you want fire click event or define event?

Comment: basically hover over the element

Comment: hover is working fine. What is the use  `c[i].click();`

Comment: @empiric the error is gone,but the pop up is not coming up which should on the click function

Comment: @SumeshTG I want hover over Apple slice when someone hover over H1 tag

Answer (score 2):

$(element).trigger('click');

View docs here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

```js
debugger;

var chart=Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 45
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Contents of Highsoft\'s weekly fruit delivery'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      innerSize: 100,
      depth: 45
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Delivered amount',
    data: [
      ['Bananas', 8],
      ['Kiwi', 3],
      ['Mixed nuts', 1],
      ['Oranges', 6],
      ['Apples', 8],
      ['Pears', 4],
      ['Clementines', 4],
      ['Reddish (bag)', 1],
      ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
    ]
  }]
});

var ch = document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-color-4");
var bx = document.getElementById("Apples");
var cv = bx;

if (ch && bx) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    ch[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
  }
  bx.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
}

function mouseOver() {
  $("#Apples").css("color", "red");
   chart.series[0].data[0].update(20);
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-color-4");
  if (c) {
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        $(c[i]).trigger("click");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<h1 id="Apples">Apples</h1>
```

Use jquery trigger inorder to fire an event programmically `$(c[i]).trigger("click");`

Comment: the popup is not coming

Comment: Where you created popup?

Comment: when u hover over apple slice a popup kind of thing comes,

Comment: Couldn't understand. Plz share is there any link or image regarding this